# No audio over HDMI with latest Raspberry Pi OS Lite official image - raspi-config not working

Tags: audio, hdmi, alsa, raspberry-pi-os-bookworm, speakers

I use a Raspberry 3B+.
After a fresh installation of latest Raspberry Pi OS Lite 64 bit (Bookworm official image : https://downloads.raspberrypi.com/raspios_lite_armhf/images/raspios_lite_armhf-2023-12-11/2023-12-11-raspios-bookworm-armhf-lite.img.xz), the default sound output is the analog headphone jack.
`speaker-test` works well.

I want sound over HDMI. So, with `raspi-config`, I changed the audio output to HDMI.
However, this doesn't work. `speaker-test` gives :

```
Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Sample format not available for playback: Invalid argument
Setting of hwparams failed: Invalid argument
```

Is this normal ? How to get sound over HDMI ?

Steps to reproduce :

- Download image here : https://downloads.raspberrypi.com/raspios_lite_armhf/images/raspios_lite_armhf-2023-12-11/2023-12-11-raspios-bookworm-armhf-lite.img.xz
- Burn to SD card, boot, choose username and password
- Run `speaker-test` and check sound output is 3.5mm jack
- Change sound output to HDMI with `sudo raspiconfig`
- Now, `speaker-test` fails

Comment: Why would you put Bookworm Lite on a Pi3B+. It is not recommended by Raspberry Pi Ltd. and most of the changes in Bookworm were to the Desktop which you aren't using. I suggest you install Legacy version (Bullseye). The Lite version is missing many things in the full image.

Comment: Why do you say Bookworm is not recommended by Raspberry Pi Ltd. ?
On the download page of their website (https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/) the first 64 versions which appear are based on Bookworm, and it says it's compatible with RPi versions >= 3B.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the comment - you CAN install and run on all models but that is different from recommendation. If you enter your Pi model in imager it will not suggest Bookworm.

Comment: Ok. I will confirm that this evening but I think the same issue appears with Bullseye.

Comment: Yes, I confirm there's exactly the same issue with Bullseye.

Comment: Have you tried with a normal OS (not Lite). The error message you posted indicates missing files (not uncommon with Lite). Alternately you could try to find where the missing file is located.

Comment: I have multiple brand new same model smart TVs and multiple 3B+ and I’m facing the same issue. I got it working a couple times while installing/removing/configuring pipewire-pulse, pulseaudio and other involved packages, but could’t determine exact actions that make it work. I tested on bookworm with desktop (32-bit) and bookworm lite (32-bit). I do have another older TV and it does work though with the same setup. Tried figuring out if maybe something is wrong with TV, dumped EDID file and checked, modified, repackaged, but without luck.